# String to date parsing error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: c#, .net, string, datetime

In my property below I m parsing string to datetime.

```
public virtual string StartTimeLocal
{
    set { StartTime = DateTime.Parse(value).ToUTCDateTime(); }
}
```

Just checked in value I have `26/1/2014 02:17 PM`

Can you please help me what wrong I m doing and how to correct it ?

Comment: What if you change `DateTime.Parse(value)` to `DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)`? (With apologies to @Mzf who got there before me)

Comment: If you ask a question about parsing errors you should always include your culture (f.e. `en-US`). Btw, why do you pass a string instead of a `DateTime` at all to this property?

Comment: @TimSchmelter to the second part it looks like this property will take an input string and then set the DateTime on the StartTime property which *is* a DateTime, normalised to UTC.

Comment: @ClickRick: isn't there already a method available for this purpose: [`DateTime.ToUniversalTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime.aspx)?

Comment: True, I'd forgotten that, but there is still a need in some cases for a property to take a string. It does depend on the application, and where/how it's being used.

Answer (score 4):

[`DateTime.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) parses *standart date and time formats*. <strike>Your string is not one of them.</strike>

You can use [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods instead.

```
string s = "26/1/2014 02:17 PM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/M/yyyy hh:mm tt", 
                          CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"), 
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
   Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
else
{
   //Your string is not a valid DateTime.
}
```

Comment: His string is standard, for en-US culture. It would work just fine if your local culture is set to en-US or culture was set explicitly.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, can you please suggest what change I should do ? I m getting data from csv file ?

Comment: @Soner Gönül, can you please suggest how I can fix it ? I m not aware how this culture thing work, my data is coming from csv file.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: this string works for 168 cultures, not only en-US.

Answer (score 3):

Your input is formatted using en-US culture settings, so you should either make sure your application runs on system with local culture set to en-US or specify culture explicitly:

```
public virtual string StartTimeLocal
{
    set { StartTime = DateTime.Parse(value, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).ToUTCDateTime(); }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the below:

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Comment: `M` fits better instead of `MM` because OP uses `1` not `01`

Comment: @Mzf sorry same result.

Comment: did you try `M` instead of `MM` ?

Comment: I update the answer - I had unneeded `/` at the end of the date format